# What distances measures perform well on content-based Recommendation Systems?

Tags: hadoop, vector, recommendation-engine, tf-idf, euclidean-distance

I want to implement a content based recommendation system that provides a list of recommended books based on user input.

I`ll be using TF-IDF to determine how important a word is to a given book and will create a Book Characteristic Vector for every Book.

I need to create a similarity matrix to determine to determine possible pair of books. I came across Euclidean Distance for doing that. Any other methods better than Euclidean?

Comment: Hey John! Just saw this question posted, actually I am working on something like this. Were you able to complete this task?

Comment: Yes, I completed it, but the results were about 40-50% accurate.

Comment: Ok! Is there any live site where you have implemented this.If it is can you please sent the link?

Answer (score 1):

These are some good distance measures you might try:

- (generalized) Jaccard distance
- Manhattan distance
- Hellinger distance
- cosine similarity